# Is this a 0.25% "precision" bleeder resistor?

Tags: resistors, identification, colour-coding

In the AC input section of a PCB, I found a resistor (in parallel with an X capacitor) with 5 color bands:

```
        BLACK - GOLD - YELLOW - GRAY - BLUE(LIGHT BLUE)
```

Sorry because now I do not have anything to take a picture of it.

It's probably rated 2W and the PCB is made  in Japan.

If I interpret it from left to right, the result is a 400 MOhms 0.25 % resistor. This is clearly wrong for a bleeder.

If I interpret it from right to left, the result is still unreasonable(68.4 Ohm). The precision is unknown as black isn't coded for any tolerance.

How should I interpret this resistor ?

Comment: What is the colour of the body of the resistor? Brown? Blue? Green?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Blue, lighter blue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a 680K 5% resistor. You're reading it backwards.

The black band is over the end cap, and should be on the right-hand side when reading the resistor. It is just to indicate orientation. Fairly common on Asian parts.

Comment: I can't accept an answer in 5 minutes (lol).

Comment: Hmmm. Strange. I haven't seen this in general guildlines.